# Angular directive not linking in test

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

To get familiar with directive testing I created the simple example shown below.  Unfortunately, the test is failing and it seems that the link function is never called. The directive does work when used within an app.

I have tried hardcoding the `message` attribute, removing the condition within the link function and even extracting the attr set from within the $watch, but the test still fails.

There has been other posts like this and the reason for those was due to the lack of a $digest call, but I do have that and I have tried moving it into the `it` spec block.

If I run a `console.log(elem[0].otherHTML)` call the scope binding seems to work

```
<wd-alert type="notice" message="O'Doole Rulz" class="ng-scope"></wd-alert>
```

What am I missing?

## alert.spec.js

```
"use strict";

describe('Alert Specs', function () {

  var scope, elem;

  beforeEach(module('myapp'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    scope.msg = "O'Doole Rulz";
    elem  = angular.element('<wd-alert type="notice" message="{{msg}}"></wd-alert>');
    $compile(elem)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
  }));

  it('shows the message', function () {
    expect(elem.text()).toContain("O'Doole Rulz");
  });

});
```

## alert.js

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('wdAlert', function() {
  return  {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('message', function() {
        if (attrs.message) {
          element.text(attrs.message);
          element.addClass(attrs.type);
        }
      })
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Instead of `scope = $rootScope`, have you tried `scope = $rootScope.$new()`? The latter is the pattern I remember seeing in the docs.

Comment: It should be just $rootScope for directives.  I just found the problem and it was a karma include issue -> using `*.js` instead of `**/*.js`.  Bad on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was a Karma configuration for the way I had the files organized.  I will leave this question up just in case it bites someone else in the ass.

```
files: [
  ...,
  'spec_path/directives/*js'      // what I originally had
  'spec_path/directives/**/*.js'  // what I needed
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this to expand on the answer for anyone else who wants to know.

I installed a third-party directive via bower.  It worked in the app, but caused tests to break.

The problem is that Grunt/Karma doesn't read the scripts in your index.html.  Instead, you need to make sure you let karma know each installed script.

For example, I used the directive ngQuickDate (a datepicker).  I added it to index.html for the app, but I needed to add it to karma.conf.js as well:

```
files: [
    ...
    'app/bower_components/ngQuickDate/dist/ng-quick-date.js'
]
```

The answer above does the same thing by means of using the `**` wildcard to mean "in all subdirectories recursively".

Hope that helps!